# How to get JSON value from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get JSON value from PHP but if one of the property values contains a forward slash "/" it fails (I'm using GET to send data for this particular scenario).

Here's how I'm sending the data (This works just fine when I don't send "/").

**UI side**

```
const dataObj = {
      description: 'my / description',
      buyer: 'Mike Brown'
    };

const dataString = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

fetch(`http://localhost:8000/clients/${dataString}`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseData) => {
         ......
      });
```

**PHP side:**

```
Route::get('/clients/{data}', function($data) {
   // This line below fails ONLY if value of description property contains "/"
   // otherwise it works just fine
   $dataToBeSaved = json_decode($data, true); 

});
```

Yes, I did some research on json_decode, but nothing very clear. Can anyone point me on the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try like this way, works for me: `$personJSON = '{"name":"Johny / Carson","title":"CTO"}';

$person = json_decode($personJSON);

echo "Name: ". $person->name . '<br/>';
echo "Title: ". $person->title;`

Comment: do you need send it as get request? if you can send it as post request this will be easier

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a good idea to pass JSON data in a URL, and you can't do it directly because it will contain characters that have meaning in URLs (e.g. /, ?, =, etc.). But if you must you have a couple options:

1. You can URL encode the string and pass it as a parameter. This wouldn't work with the route you have, but it has the benefit of not needing to do anything else. You can just get the value from the parameter.

```js
const dataObj = {
  description: 'my / description',
  buyer: 'Mike Brown'
};

const dataString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataObj));

console.log(`https://example.com/clients?data=${dataString}`);
```

2. Or you can base64 encode it. This doesn't by default create URL safe strings, so you'll have to replace a few characters to make it URL safe. That also means you'll have to do the reverse on the server. This solution will work with your route.

```js
const base64UrlEncode = function(str) {
  return btoa(str)
    // this character have meaning in URLs so we need to replace them
    // with something else. we'll have to reverse this on the server.
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=+$/, '');
};

const dataObj = {
  description: 'my / description',
  buyer: 'Mike Brown'
};

const dataString = base64UrlEncode(JSON.stringify(dataObj));

console.log(`https://example.com/clients/${dataString}`);
```

And to decode on the server:

```php
function base64UrlDecode($encodedStr) {
  // undo the character replacements we did when encoding the string
  $unreplace1 = str_replace('-', '+', $encodedStr);
  $unreplace2 = str_replace('_', '/', $unreplace1);

  return base64_decode($unreplace2);
}

Route::get('/clients/{data}', function($data) {
   $dataToBeSaved = json_decode(base64UrlDecode($data), true); 
});
```

One thing to note with this solution is that web servers usually have a limit for the length of URLs (e.g. Apache's default is 8,177 characters). Also, there is usually a limit to the size of the "filename" in the URL (the last component in the path). Apache's default is 255 bytes/characters. So if your base64 encoded JSON is longer than 255 characters, it won't work. A better solution is to pass the data as part of the request body (i.e. as a POST request). That way you won't have a limit and you won't need to encode it beyond converting it to JSON.

Comment: I tried your first solution and it didn't work, also what is btoa? doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @progx When you say "it didn't work", how so? Did you get the $data value on the serverside? What did it look like? [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) base64 encodes a string.

Comment: @progx I realized you can't URI encode a string to make it part of a URL path. You would have to pass it as a URL parameter. I updated my answer accordingly. Though the base64 solution should work with the route you have. I just tested on a server of mine and it worked.

Comment: @progx I also added a note about URL limits at the end of the answer. You'll likely run into that when passing JSON data as part of the URL path.

Comment: Btw, sorry, I accidentally tagged `progx` for some reason.